# View based NSTableView receive delayed edit actions

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I want to display a pop over from my view based table cells whenever the user clicks on the cell and waits or double clicks on it. The double click part is easy, with the double click action, but I cannot find a way to do on a click and wait. I can get the selection of the table, but I want it to be similar to if it was a text field (where it wouldn't start editing right away) or the object library in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the table view delegate method, tableViewSelectionDidChange:, and in that method, call performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: to add any delay you want before showing the popover.

Comment: It's not just a delay, but waiting to see if the user does something else. For instance, they could drag it, or be selecting it to delete.

Comment: It's been a while but @rdelmar has the right idea. The only thing is that if the user performs another action then you need to cancel your delayed performSelector.

Answer (score 0):

This document is describing how to be notified on the text field editing begin/end.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1551/_index.html

These are essential delegate method to implement to handle them.

```
func control(control: NSControl, textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    return  true
}
func control(control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    return  true
}
```

### Explanation

I believe you're talking something like "delayed editing" like renaming in Finder.
User single-clicks an entry, and waits for a little, and it becomes editable soon.

I finally figured out how this works. The "delayed-editing" is more likely to be a side-effect of double-action(`setDoubleAction:`) rather than formal feature. Because you have a double-click action, the table-view has to wait for double-clicking interval to determine the second click would happen or not.

If you don't `setDoubleAction:`, the editing starts immediately on the text field. But by setting a double-action, we can make it to be delayed. And the rest of work is just getting notified when editing starts.

Above codes are all for that. I checked this is working on OS X 10.10. 
NSButton does seem to be delayed. I hope this helps.

### Another Solution

If the above method doesn't work, here's another approach.

- Prepare a `NSTextField` subclass.

  ```
  @interface  AAATextField: NSTextField
  @end
  @implementation AAATextField
  - (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
      NSLog(@"%@", @"editing is starting...");
      return  YES;
  }
  @end
  ```
- Prepare a `NSTableCellView` subclass.

  ```
  @interface BBBTableCellView : NSTableCellView
  @property(nonatomic,readwrite,strong) NSTextField*  exampleTextField;
  @end

  @implementation BBBTableCellView
  @synthesize exampleTextField;
  - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
      self    =   [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
      if (self) {
          exampleTextField    =   [[AAATextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 100, 20)];
          [self addSubview:exampleTextField];
          [self setTextField:exampleTextField];
      }
      return  self;
  }
  @end
  ```
- Use it with `NStableView`.

  ```
  - (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
      BBBTableCellView*   v   =   [[BBBTableCellView alloc] init];
      v.exampleTextField.stringValue  =   @"ABCDE";
      return v;
  }
  ```